How can I reduce the polycount of a high-poly model without losing alot of details?
Recently, I have create some models in Blender. There are just high-poly pine trees with snow on top but they have an extremely high poly-count(About a million vertices)! I want to use these trees for my Terrain in unity. But my laptop is a very low end computer with a weak GPU and I want any computer with a low-end GPU to be able to run my game at atleast 25 fps. My Laptop struggles when I look at 3-5 trees in Unity.
I used the 'Sapling Tree Gen' addon to create my trees and converted the curves into a mesh. I selected some faces and used the 'Real Snow' addon to add snow to my trees.
I used the 'Sapling Tree Gen' addon to create my trees and converted the curves into a mesh. I selected some faces and used the 'Real Snow' addon to add snow to my trees.
I have tried to lower my poly-count using voxels(remesh), the decimate modifier, InstaMesh, etc. All my attempts to lower the polycount of my trees as either ended in Blender freezing(since my laptop is weak) or made my models look terrible.
On Unity, I have tried to use 'Mesh Compression' on high in Import Settings. I have not seen any improvement in performance whatsoever.
I expect my trees to look good enough to be believable, since I am making a horror game.

you can try using the decimate modifier with the ratio setting and set it to a value from 0.6 to 0.7. The decimate modifier removes geometry from the model without losing out on too much detail. You can tweak this value on your own as well as per reduced vertex count you need without losing out on the model's details

I have used the Decimate Modifier in Blender and am currently implementing LOD models into my Game.
I found that removing the material and modifiers applied to the snow model(from RealSnow) before joining them into my Tree Mesh helps to reduce the polycount by alot.
I will inform you about the improvement in performance

Use LOD (Level of Detail) models: Create multiple versions of your tree models with lower levels of detail to switch between them based on distance from the camera. This will help reduce the polycount and improve performance.
Bake textures and shadows: Instead of having detailed geometry for snow on top of the trees, consider baking these details into a texture or using a shader to simulate the effect. This will reduce the overall polycount of the models.

I am currently implementing LOD models into my Game.
I found that removing the material and modifiers applied to the snow model(from RealSnow) before joining them into my Tree Mesh helps to reduce the polycount by alot.
I will let you know about the final results on performance
